# Do programs keep "doing stuff" when I change desktops in Ubuntu?

Tags: multiple-desktops

This might sound weird and/or stupid, but if I have a game running on one desktop where I'm just running down a clock before I can do the next thing, and I change desktops, does "Game Desktop" suspend, or does it just keep going while I'm on "Work Desktop"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing where you could just try it and see...

Comment: It would be if I was home.  Unfortunately I'm at work and can't test it and wanted to just ask someone who knew more than I did before wasting time trying to do something that doesn't work the way I expected.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more your response annoys me, Eliah.  On a site where people come to ask questions, you decide to come off like a total prick when someone asks a question with a simple answer than can be simply answered as it was below.  Thank you for your valuable efforts to make noobs feel welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing desktops will not "suspend" anything in the other desktops. It's just like putting a different window on top.

Comment: Definitely the more helpful answer.  Thank you very much for the quick, simple, and courteous reply.